# Does whatsapp backup media on Google Drive?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive, media-files, google-backup

I linked my Google drive account with whatsapp for backup. They give the impression that all accompanying media including [video and images](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921#googledrive) gets backed up too.

```
You can back up your chats and media to Google Drive, so if you switch Android phones or get a new one, your chats and media are transferrable. To use Google Drive, make sure the following is true:

 - Your device must be synced with Google Drive. Google Play Services
   must be installed (only available for Android 2.3.4 and later). 
 - Your Google Drive account must have enough space for all of your WhatsApp
   data
 - Your phone must have enough free space to create the backup.
```

However, it seams that there is only 19mb of hidden data on the Drive after a full backup.

And restoring whatsapp to another device, I get an image not found error when I try to open recent images.

[image]

So what is the case? Is whatsapp dishonest if they do not state the limitations of their backup feature? Especially when we need to move images off the device, due to space constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you see that size is not matching, it's likely that you didn't tick *include videos* in WhatsApp settings

[image]

- If you have ticked it and it still doesn't match, that's strange because I have restored to test, when starting to use this feature and **all** media plus charts are backed up.

> does whatsapp keep previous backups on Google Drive ?

**No**

[WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921) says :

> Every time you run a Google Drive backup on a Google account, the previous Google Drive backup will be overwritten. There is no way to restore an older Google Drive backup.

So if for some reason your backup doesn't include videos after ticking it also, it makes sense to take a fresh backup on WiFi

Comment: But when I restored the media to a different device and tried to open images, I get an image not found error popup.

Comment: I can't answer why - only reason would be that your backup was not complete / corrupted.  Quick search on internet doesn't show similar complaints. You would expect multiple hits if this was truly a bug